# How to handle resizing an SVG element through CSS for something like mouse clicks?

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I want to draw a path, on an SVG element where a user has clicked (so they could do something akin to using a paint brush).

I am loading an svg through the `<object>` tag, and in the SVG, there is already a path (that is empty).  My idea is to set the path attributes with the clicked position.

This kind of works, but if the SVG element is resized in CSS, the clicked positions do not line up with the SVG element.

As I simple test case, I created a page to draw a small circle wherever the use clicked.  If the SVG element had no styling on it, (it was essentially at the top left corner of the page) this worked, but if I made the element something like `width: 50%` in the CSS, the circle position was way, way off.

You can see a basic example, [here](https://jsbin.com/gapicovawo/1/edit?html,css,js,console,output) but it only really works to show you the concept, as it appears JSBIN does not support the `<object>` element or something.

Really it's the conceptual question of what happens when you resize and SVG with CSS and how do you normalize clicked positions after it has been resized?

Comment: How about using a library like d3?

Comment: That is a good idea but I am curious if I can draw an arc from a point on my screen without an entire library.

Comment: okay, if you like, go through this example. http://comexile.blogspot.com/2016/08/simple-mapping-tool-with-d3.html